# How do you update XML content in Jackrabbit using an XPath query?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jackrabbit, jcr

I am using Jackrabbit 2.4.0 and I am having trouble updating XML which has been imported using:

```
session.importXML(node.getPath(), is, ImportUUIDBehavior.IMPORT_UUID_CREATE_NEW);
session.save();
```

I have the following code that does the XML updating:

```
public void updateXML(InputStream is, String nodePath)
        throws RepositoryException, IOException, NamingException
{
    Session session = getSession();

    try
    {
        logger.debug("Updating path '" +nodePath +"'...");

        session.importXML(nodePath, is, ImportUUIDBehavior.IMPORT_UUID_COLLISION_REPLACE_EXISTING);
        session.save();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (session != null)
            session.logout();
    }
}
```

Assuming I have a the following imported to Jackrabbit under `/notes`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note xmlns="http://testuri.org/note"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://testuri.org/note file:///path/to/note.xsd"
      xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <id>123</id>
    <to>Me</to>
    <from>You</from>
    <heading>Meeting at five</heading>
    <body>With this you are hereby invited to the important meeting at five.</body>

</note>
```

Why does the following code to update the XML not work:

```
    InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("note-update.xml");

    serviceXML.updateXML(is, "//notes");
```

and I get the following error:

```
    org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.conversion.MalformedPathException: '//notes' is not a valid path. double slash '//' not allowed.
```

I do however have the following imported:

```
/
/jcr:primaryType = rep:root
/jcr:system
/notes
/notes/jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
/notes/note:note
/notes/note:note/xsi:schemaLocation = http://testuri.org/note file:///path/to/note.xsd
/notes/note:note/jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
/notes/note:note/note:id
/notes/note:note/note:id/jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
/notes/note:note/note:id/jcr:xmltext
/notes/note:note/note:id/jcr:xmltext/jcr:xmlcharacters = 123
/notes/note:note/note:id/jcr:xmltext/jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
/notes/note:note/note:to
/notes/note:note/note:to/jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
/notes/note:note/note:to/jcr:xmltext
/notes/note:note/note:to/jcr:xmltext/jcr:xmlcharacters = Me
/notes/note:note/note:to/jcr:xmltext/jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
/notes/note:note/note:from
/notes/note:note/note:from/jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
/notes/note:note/note:from/jcr:xmltext
/notes/note:note/note:from/jcr:xmltext/jcr:xmlcharacters = You
/notes/note:note/note:from/jcr:xmltext/jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
/notes/note:note/note:heading
/notes/note:note/note:heading/jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
/notes/note:note/note:heading/jcr:xmltext
/notes/note:note/note:heading/jcr:xmltext/jcr:xmlcharacters = Meeting at five
/notes/note:note/note:heading/jcr:xmltext/jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
/notes/note:note/note:body
/notes/note:note/note:body/jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
/notes/note:note/note:body/jcr:xmltext
/notes/note:note/note:body/jcr:xmltext/jcr:xmlcharacters = With this you are hereby invited to the important meeting at five.
/notes/note:note/note:body/jcr:xmltext/jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
```

I have one single entry.

Let's say I would like to update the note with id 123, how would I go about doing that using XPath?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work'? Do you get an error message or is the change ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Session.importXml` takes a String `path` as its first argument. As such, you should specify the location where to import the nodes.

In your case, I believe that is `/notes`.

Comment: Correct indeed! Thanks! :)
Any chance you could also give me an example of how I can update by id as mentioned in my updated question above?

Comment: Actually, no. This adds another <note> entry with the updated node. The old one is still there. The idea is to have it replaced.

Comment: Have you tried using  `ImportUUIDBehavior.IMPORT_UUID_COLLISION_REPLACE_EXISTING` instead of `ImportUUIDBehavior.IMPORT_UUID_CREATE_NEW`?

Comment: Well, as shown in the code above, that's what I'm doing when trying to update. However, I believe I need to have a more complicated XPath, but I'm not sure how it should look like.

Comment: By reading the spec, this seems to be the way importXml works. You probably need to fall back to removing the node yourself before importing.